# How to Set Timer in HTML?

Tags: html

I want to show Loading(Gif) image for 3 seconds and want to open a website link(Say http://example.com), after the timer(3 Seconds) is complete. How to set timeout in HTML?

[image]

Comment: JavaScript `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the html redirect

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://stackoverflow.com/" />
```

The number in `content` means seconds until the page is redirected to the next paramenter, `url`.

Comment: Thanks! This is what i needed. You're the best.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript for that: [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
setTimeout(function( ){ location.href = 'http://google.com'; }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by using JavaScript's `setTimeout`

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout( function(){
        window.location = "http://www.example.com";
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!